# bash get a regular expression number up to 2 digits

Tags: regex, bash, digit

I simply need to know how to make a regex that accepts a number that has up to 2 digits

All I have just now is

```
^[0-9]{2}$
```

Which would match a number with exactly 2 digits, but I don't know how to specify "match a number which has up to 2 digits".

Also, if there is a way to make sure that this number isn't 0 then that would be a plus, otherwise I can check that with Bash.

Thanks ! :)

Note that the input variable comes from read -p "make a choice" Number

EDITING MY POST - SHOWING CODE IN CONTEXT :

```
while true; do
    read -p "Please key in the number of the engineer of your choice, or leave empty to select them all: " Engineer
    if [ -z "$Engineer" ]; then
        echo "No particular user specified, all engineers will be selected."
        UserIdSqlString="Transactions.Creator!=0 "
        break
    else
        if [[ $Engineer =~ ^[0-9]{1,2}$ && $Engineer -ne 0 ]]; then
            echo "If you want a specific engineer type their number otherwise leave blank"  
        else
            echo "yes"
            break
        fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: Are you using `grep` or `sed` or something?

Comment: I've edited my post. I don't mind involving grep or sed at all :)

Comment: @Bluz, you have the `if-else` backward. `if [[ $Engineer =~ ^[0-9]{1,2}$ && $Engineer -ne 0 ]]; ` returns true when you have a non-zero two digit number set into `Engineer` so `echo "yes"` should follow this

Comment: lol I am a doughnut...shows that I need a coffee break!! Thanks mate! :)

Comment: Your test still has a problem when `Engineer`'s value is `08` or `09`. Please see my comment in 1_CR's answer below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the bash [[[](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression) conditional expression supports extended regular expressions.

```
[[ $number =~ ^[0-9]{,2}$ && $number -ne 0 ]]
```

or as the inimitable @gniourf_gniourf points out in his comments, the following is needed to handle numbers with leading zeroes correctly

```
[[ $number =~ ^[0-9]{,2}$ ]] && ((number=10#$number))
```

Comment: mmmhhh....doesn't seem to work :( I can add a zero. Note that the variable comes from read -p . I don't know if that is relevant but I'll edit my question just in case.

Comment: @Bluz, have you tried `if [[ $number =~ ^[0-9]{,2}$ && $number -ne 0 ]]; then echo 'yes'; fi` after `read -p "make a choice" number`?

Comment: yes I have, let me edit again to show you my code. Also, is that not supposed to be {1,2} instead of {,2} as you put in your expression ? Did you do that on purpose or is this a typo? I tried with {1,2} as well but still not working :(

Comment: @Bluz, `{,2}` is as intended, that's an accepted form of "interval expression"

Comment: Be aware that this solution is broken in the case when the value of `number` is `08` or `09`, since in the checking `$number -ne 0`, bash will try to interpret `08` or `09` as a number in radix 8 (because prefixed by a `0`) and this will throw an error.

Comment: Maybe `[[ $number =~ ^[[:digit:]]{1,2}$ ]] && ((number=10#$number))` would be better: it will assign to `number` its value in radix 10, even if there are leading zeros, and at the same time check it's not zero. `:)`

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, looking forward to your book on `bash` ;-) Incorporated in the answer

Comment: Thank you 1_CR! Though, I'm not planning to write any book yet, there's still so much to learn!

Comment: hey thanks guys for your additional comments and for going the extramile! 
I did actually notice the same thing and solved it by :
$Engineer =~ ^[0-9]{1,2}$ && $Engineer -ne 0 && $Engineer =~ ^[^0]

And because the maximum of digits allowed is 2 then 001 wouldn't work either :)

Answer (score 7):

```
^([1-9]|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1})$
```

matches every number from 1,2,3...99

Answer (score 6):

The answer that I found is:

```
^[0-9]{1,2}$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" -gt 0 ] 2>/dev/null ;then 
    echo "$1 is number." 
else 
    echo 'no.' 
fi
```